# Using Spring's property injection without having to launch up the whole context

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I want to run some unit tests without the need of the Spring context because of speed reasons.
But I also like the way I can inject files into my tests

Here is an example testcode I use:

```
@ContextConfiguration()
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class XmlRestructureApplierTest {
  @Value("classpath:export.xml")
  private Resource exportedXML;
  private XmlRestructureApplier applier;


  @Test
  public void shouldRestructureArrayToObjectWithGivenKey() throws IOException, XPathExpressionException, SAXException {
    List<JSONObject> productsAsJSONObjects = XmlElementExtractor.extractToJSON(exportXML.getInputStream(), "PRV");
    assertThat(productsAsJSONObjects).hasSize(6);
  }
}
```

I'd like to have only the convenient way of using `@Value` without launching the whole time consuming context.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: SO you want features provided by a framework, but don't want to use the framework? IN comparison you want to use JPA annotations, but not hibernate to generate a query but still want a query. This test looks like a unit test but written as an integration test (judging from the `@Autowired`). If you don't wan that then don't use Spring for your test, just write a plain unit test instantiate the object yourself, read the `export.xml` yourself (or read using a `ClassPathResource`).

Comment: Thanks I am fully aware of what I demand. And I am aware how to get the resources by vanilla methods. Still I'd like to use parts of the framework rather then the whole mashup. The `@Autowired` part was left in by mistake. Will edit it

Comment: You need at least the `SpringRunner` to have that feature enabled. But why bother with that if you don't really need it. You would need an empty config together with `@ContextConfiguration` next to the `@RunWith`. All in all imho to much overkill to just use this feature which you can get using a simple `new ClassPathResource("export.xml");`. Which is faster and doesn't rely on any magic.

Comment: Somehow true. Maybe I will do it that way. But it isn't the answer of that special question tbh

Comment: Depends on how you look at it. Just using `@Value` to get a hardcoded resource is overkill (imho) and enabling Spring (Boot) features in your unit test (which then becomes more then just a unit test!) is overkill.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok you convinced me! Thanks for the headsup. I will not use it because it's easy to type anymore and try to me more clever next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use test empty configuration for such test, it will improve performance. In following example, `@SpringBootTest` load only embedded `EmptyTestContext` instead of searching for all `SpringBootConfiguration`:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class DemoMvcApplicationTest {
    @Value("${test.value}")
    private String value;

    @Test
    public void propertyHasValidValue() {
        assertThat(value).isEqualTo("TestValue1");
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class EmptyTestContext {}
}
```

Also for more readability you could add:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = DemoMvcApplicationTest.EmptyTestContext.class)
```

It has the same effect.

**Update**, more lightweight variant:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class DemoMvcApplicationTest {
    @Value("${test.value}")
    private String value;

    @Test
    public void propertyHasValidValue() {
        assertThat(value).isEqualTo("TestValue1");
    }

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    public static class EmptyTestContext {}
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way? So spring has nothing to supply that out of the box? I mean it's a proper use-case isn't it?
Also is your approach best practise for that?

Comment: Unfortunately it is the only way that I know. By my opinion it is proper use-case if you want to control application configuration. For example you use `application.yml` and is really hard to find additional space that broke your config.

Comment: Using `@SpringBootTest` with an empty config just for the purpose of using `@Value` is overkill. Use an `@ContextConfiguration` with an empty config instead. Apparently usage of Spring Boot isn't interesting in this case. using `@SpringBootTest` enables stil a lot of Spring Boot (auto) configuration.features which aren't needed.

Comment: @M. Deinum, thanks, I have just added variant with `@ContextConfiguration`